# If statement doesn't trigger

Tags: php

I have a really odd issue.

This is my code, as-is:

```
<?php
    $cur = file_get_contents("./req.txt");
    if(($_POST['bid'] >= $cur + 0.25) & $_POST['contact'] !== '')
    {
        $fi2 = "./req.txt";
        file_put_contents($fi2, $_POST['bid']);
        echo "<font color=\"red\" size=\"5\">Success</font>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<font color=\"red\" size=\"5\">Error.</font>";
    }
?>
```

When it's like that, it works fine.

But, if I change the `else` to `if($_POST['bid'] >= $cur + 0.25)` (which is copied and pasted from above), the page loads fine and it doesn't run the `file_put_contents`, but it doesn't echo `Error`. This is what the code looks like changed:

```
<?php
    $cur = file_get_contents("./req.txt");
    if(($_POST['bid'] >= $cur + 0.25) & $_POST['contact'] !== '')
    {
        $fi2 = "./req.txt";
        file_put_contents($fi2, $_POST['bid']);
        echo "<font color=\"red\" size=\"5\">Success</font>";
    }
    if($_POST['bid'] >= $cur + 0.25)
    {
        echo "<font color=\"red\" size=\"5\">Error.</font>";
    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the code that doesn't work, rather than describing the changes.

Comment: it sounds like you have a syntax error and the page isn't executing at all. That's the only way that code _after_ the `if` could prevent the `if` from triggering.

Comment: The page loads fine. CSS and html run. I put `echo "test";` on the bottom line and it worked fine.

Comment: Please clarify. When you run the first version, it echoes `Success`, but if you run the second version with the same input it doesn't echo anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `$_POST['bid'] >= $cur + 0.25` is `false`, then both your codes in the if won't be executed.

The first piece of code will come into the `else`, but the second won't come into the second `if`.

Comment: Whoops... Thanks for pointing this out. Always the silly mistakes haha.

Comment: When you said the first version "worked", I thought you meant it echoed Success.

Answer (score 0):

& is the bitwise and operator in PHP, which has higher precedence than the !== operator. Try replacing the & with &&.

Comment: Good catch, but how would that explain what he's seeing?